# php search for [ ] and check its data and replace it by new text

Tags: php

in php i want to search text between `[ ]` and if it is my desired text then replace it by new text

**for example** :

```
dear [code_user] your new order code is [code_order]
```

**final result should be**:

```
dear john your new order code is 5504
```

i did like this: but it repeat name many time and not working

```
$message = $smsTM->text; // we should send sms by Suitable template

$message = preg_replace('/[code_user]/', $userName, $message);
$message = preg_replace('/[code_reserve]/', 'hp', $message);
```

any solution?

Comment: If you have specific strings you want to replace, why not just use `str_replace()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about with a simple `str_replace()` instead of regex way? with `str_replace()`, you can use multiple string as search and replace on array. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
<?php
$string = 'dear [code_user] your new order code is [code_order]';
$result = str_replace(['[code_user]','[code_order]'],['john','5504'], $string);
echo $result;
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ChCfc

Answer (score 2):

Heres something I wrote earlier, but used `{{ }}` https://gist.github.com/lcherone/f7ef70406c7c84aeb7d64566afb63bb8,

The following is a changed to use `[ ]` allows for `[placeholder]` or `[ placeholder ]`

```
<?php
$vars = [
  'code_user' => 'Loz',
  'code_order' => 5504
];

$template = 'Dear [code_user] your new order code is [code_order]!';

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[[ ]{0,}([\w\_-]{1,})[ ]{0,}\]/', function ($match) use ($vars) {
  return array_key_exists($match[1], $vars) ? $vars[$match[1]] : '';
}, $template);

// Dear Loz your new order code is 5504!
echo $result;
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/W2GFO

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace()` with array to replace multiple occurrence like below:

```
<?php
$your_string = "dear [code_user] your new order code is [code_order]. xxxxxxxx [code_user]";
$final_string = str_replace(array('[code_user]', '[code_order]'), array('John Doe', '123456'), $your_string);
echo $final_string;
?>
```